# why i am getting this error message in python ? IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

I am new in python and I am trying to make a simple cicle for this my code:

```
for i in range(0,5) :
    if i==0 :
    b=b.append(1)

else: 
result=(b[i-1]+1) 
b.append(result)
return(result)
```

File "", line 5
    b=b.append(1)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

how can I fill a vector or matrix  with my results?

Comment: You'd need to show some properly formatted code to get help with this one. Edit your question, highlight the code block, and click the `{}` button in the toolbar to format it.

Comment: move the lines below the `if` and the `else` a 4 spaces (or 1 tab) to the right

Comment: You might want to start with [a tutorial](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php) to understand the basic principles.

Comment: Format the exception as code as well. You can put `<p/>` to create a visual break between code and exception. It helps to see everything that comes off the console in monospace.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari When editing 1) don't just apply your own favorite code style and 2) don't apply changes to code that will invalidate the question and answers. The specific problem of the question was due to the incorrect indentation that you 'fixed' with your edit.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: and it got approved by two reviewers ...

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't indent your code correctly. It should look probably like this:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    if i==0 :
        b=b.append(1)
    else: 
        result=(b[i-1]+1) 
        b.append(result)
return(result)
```

where the body of the for loop is indented, and so do the bodies of the if and else statements, relatively to their respected statements.

Comment: Thanks , I tryied to write a code as you suggested but now i am getting another error: b=b.append(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append',

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because python uses white space to determine when blocks start and end.  You have to use indenting to open \ close all of your logic blocks.

```
if thing > thing2
    inside_if_stuff = 1

the_if_has_now_ended_and_Im_doing_other_stuff
```

There's no characters like {} to open and close logic in python

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you use a backslash?

Comment: when I said open \ close?

Comment: Yup. I usually see a forward slash in that context.

Comment: TBH I've never really noticed it lol prob cause I have giant hands and it's easier for me to hit above the enter key